# Curl: callback for Multiple download progress

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I have two threads which call the same routine to download the file using curl.How can I print the progress of each file being downloaded simulataneously using curl? I think curl pointer is the only variable which can distinguished between two downloads in progress callback. How can I make use of it to print the progress of each file when progress callback is called each time? Please advice.Thanks.Below is snippet.

```
struct myprog
{
   char filename[10];
}

static int txfrprogress(void *p,
                curl_off_t  dltotal, curl_off_t  dlnow,
                curl_off_t  ultotal, curl_off_t  ulnow)
{
   static L7_uint32 cnt=0;
   L7_uchar8 buf[32] = {0};
   struct myprog *mp = (struct myprog*)p;

   cnt++;
   if(!(cnt%15000)) {
     sprintf(buf,"%3d%%",(int)((dlnow/dltotal)*100));
     printf("Completed %s download for %s\n",buf,mp->filename);
   }

   return 0;
}

int mymain(char *str) 
{
 struct myprog prog= {0};
 char filename[10]={0};
 CURL *curl;
 /*copy namestring received as arguement into filename*/
 curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
 strcpy(prog.filename,filename);
 curl = curl_easy_init();
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, txfrprogress);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, &prog);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
 /*some code**/
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA.html) pointer to point to a struct of yours that for example contains whatever you need to identify that individual transfer. That could be a CURL *, a number, an ID, a file name or whatever else you think is good and suitable. Or all of those.